# Record lost when using date as key for TreeMultimap in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a scheduler where events created are tag to the date. Thus by selecting a date, all events tagged to the date will be shown. I tried doing this with TreeMultimap from google, but I realised not all the records relevant to the date selected are returned. I am wondering is there any known issue using date as the key for TreeMultimap or is purely problem of my code.

```
TreeMultimap<Date, EventInstance> dateToEventMultimap = TreeMultimap.create();

            // Build multimap.
            Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cal2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            cal1.clear(); // Clears the values of all the time fields.
            cal2.clear();
            for (EventInstance eventInstance : myEventList) {
                cal1.setTime(eventInstance.getTimeDate());
                cal2.set(cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dateToEventMultimap.put(cal2.getTime(), eventInstance);                  
            }
```

Comment: Does the date contain a time part? Did you take this into account?

Comment: Aren't you mutating the Date somewhere? When the Map/Multimap key changes, everything may happen. Avoiding mutable objects as keys is nearly always a good idea.

Comment: @BalusC I want to get all the events for the date irregardless of the time part. Thus I am only using year,month,and day of the month to retrieve the events from the list which have the time format like this 20110509T120500

Comment: I guess BalusC and z7sg are probably right. I realised this issue only happens when there are 2 events of the same date and time.

Answer (score 1):

If a mutable object is used as a key and it gets modified, the record will no longer be found, as the hash will be different. It will remain in the old hash "bin", but the hash map implementation will search it in a "bin" based on the new hash key, and it won't be there (unless by pure chance, which is rather small for good hash code implementation).